# Issue with Google translate

Tags: c#, google-translate

I'm creating application that translates text. I got most of the code right but somehow I'm stuck on this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.API.Translate;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace translator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List listLanguage = Language.TranslatableCollection.ToList();
        private List translatableLanguage = new List();
        private SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        public Form1()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Where 'List' up there gives me an error but I don't know what's wrong. I'm working in VS 2012 in C#.

Comment: Can you specify the error you get?

Comment: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type argument.

Comment: You need to tell the `List` what **type** it has.  For example, if `Language.TranslatableCollection.ToList()` returns a List of `Language.TranslatableCollection` objects, it would be `private List<Language.TranslatableCollection> listLanguage = Language.TranslatableCollection.ToList();`

Comment: In addition to the comments above, you can see what type you are expecting the method to return by hovering over it in the IDE; `Language.TranslatableCollection.ToList()` will tell you what it will return.

Answer (score 1):

he List requires a Type.

i would find what type you are expecting and add that to the code.

i.e.

```
private List<Language> listLanguage = Language.TranslatableCollection.ToList();
private List<Language> translatableLanguage = new List<Language>();
```

Comment: This worked but when I run the program this pops out:

"An unhandled exception of type 'Google.API.GoogleServiceException' occurred in GoogleTranslateAPI.dll". Do you know what it might be, I mean is there something wrong with google api

Comment: I would guess the Google API is Fine ;) i would raise another question and include the full stack trace and section of code that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is no such class as `List`. I think you mean the `List<T>` class in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. This means your instantiation will look like this:

```
//'Translatable' is just a dummy class name
private List<Translatable> listLanguage = Language.TranslatableCollection.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Collections.List requires the type of the content.. Like this

```
Private List<string> mylist = new List<string>()
```

if you are referring to a list in another namespace, provide the namespace as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what kind of list you want to use.
Especially if you are working on Generic.List.
For example:

```
private List<YourType> field = new List<YourType>();
```

Read more about difference between generic and collections:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx